# glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &rect) returns GL_INVALID_ENUM on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to get OpenGL window's size before `glkView:drawInRect:` is called. I desided to use `glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &rect)` (and not `self.bounds` or similar) to be more platform independent, but it has `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

Here is the testing code:

```
#define SHOW {\
  struct { GLint x, y, w, h; } rect;\
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, (GLint*)&rect);\
  printf("%s %d %d\n", __FUNCTION__, rect.w, rect.h);\
}

...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { SHOW; ... }
- (void)viewDidLoad { SHOW; ... }
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { SHOW; ... }
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { SHOW; ... }
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews { SHOW; ... }
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect { SHOW; ... }
```

Here is the output:

```
-[ViewController viewDidLoad] 0 0
-[ViewController viewWillAppear:] 0 0
-[ViewController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] 0 0
-[ViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews] 0 0
-[ViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews] 0 0
-[ViewController glkView:drawInRect:] 1024 768
-[ViewController viewDidAppear:] 1024 768
-[ViewController glkView:drawInRect:] 1024 768
```

Why is `glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &rect)` not available prior to glkView:drawInRect:? Should `GL_VIEWPORT` be somehow initialized?

Comment: provide more info. Are you using GLKit? Or are you manually setting up buffers? How are you setting up model, view and projection matrices?